# How to NSLog a Call stack when a program is running?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there a way to get the call stack? lets say i have a function that gets called by many other functions, but I need to know who called it.

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Of course there is. If you can use the Cocoa framework:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```

([Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

If you can't use it:

```
#include <execinfo.h>

int size = 256;
void *stack[size];
size = backtrace(stack, size);

char **syms = backtrace_symbols(stack, size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("Frame #%d: %s\n", i, syms[i]);
}
free(syms);
```

([Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/backtrace_symbols.3.html))

Answer (score 4):

See `NSThread callStackSymbols`.